# Proving $\|u+v\|^2 = 4\langle u,v \rangle \implies u = v$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a True/False question in my textbook, and I'm trying to solve it:

Let $u,v$ be $2$ vectors in a vector space $V$.

$\|u+v\|^2 = 4\langle u,v \rangle \implies u = v$

I was able to prove the converse:

$u = v \implies \|u+v\|^2 = \|2u\|^2 = 4 \|u\|^2 = 4\langle u,u\rangle = 4\langle u,v\rangle.$

How do we prove/disprove the other way?

Comment: Try expanding $\|u + v\|^2$ and $\|u - v\|^2$ in terms of inner products.

Comment: It should be noted this is for $V$ a vector space over $\Bbb R$; if it's over $\Bbb C$, the theorem is $\Vert u+v\Vert^2=4\Re\langle u,\,v\rangle\implies u=v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPOILER: This is the full solution so try doing it on your own first.

First we state
\begin{align}
\lVert u + v \rVert^2 &= \langle u+v, u+v\rangle \\
&= \langle u, u+v \rangle + \langle v, u+v \rangle \\
&= \langle u, u \rangle + \langle u, v \rangle + \langle v, u \rangle + \langle v, v \rangle \\
&= \langle u, u \rangle + 2\langle u, v \rangle + \langle v, v \rangle
\end{align}
Now suppose
$$
\lVert u + v \rVert^2 = 4 \langle u, v \rangle
$$
then this implies 
\begin{align}
\langle u, u \rangle + 2 \langle u, v \rangle + \langle v, v \rangle &= 4 \langle u, v \rangle \\
\langle u, u \rangle + \langle v, v \rangle &= 2 \langle u, v \rangle \\
\langle u, u \rangle - 2\langle u, v \rangle + \langle v, v \rangle &= 0 \\
\langle u, u - v \rangle - \langle u, v \rangle + \langle v, v\rangle &= 0 \\
\langle u, u - v \rangle + \langle v-u, v\rangle &= 0 \\
\langle u, u - v \rangle - \langle u-v, v\rangle &= 0 \\
\langle u, u - v \rangle - \langle v, u-v \rangle &= 0 \tag{symmetry} \\
\langle u - v, u - v \rangle &= 0
\end{align}
which by the properties of an innerproduct implies $u = v$.

Comment: How did u get from $\langle u, u - v \rangle + \langle v-u, v\rangle = 0$ to the last equation?

Comment: I've added some steps

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\|u-v\|^{2}=\|u+v\|^{2} -4 \langle u, v \rangle$.